# why three quotation coming in fopen, """aaaa""","""bbb"""

Tags: php

it is an example of fopen

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

it's output is

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
"""aaaa""","""bbb"""
```

can any one say me why in """aaaa""","""bbb""" why three quotation in place of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the strings you're converting have quotes in them. Quotes are escaped in CSV files by doubling them, that is, `"abc"` becomes `""abc""`. The third quotes are the "normal" CSV quotes that wrap strings.

You don't need to provide the quotes yourself for `fputcsv()` so you can just use `array( 'aaa', 'bbb' )`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way of including a double-quote in a string - if you just write the double-quote, it will terminate the string, so you have to escape it somehow. The particular mechanism chosen to escape it here is to write `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Because double quotes are special in CSV; the example strings contain double quotes, which are escaped by `fputcsv` by doubling them, and because the string contains escaped quotes, it has to be wrapped in yet another pair of double quotes. This has nothing to do with `fopen`, it's just how CSV works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach to look like this:

```
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $item) {
        fput($fp, $fields . ",");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the third array there is quotation which is being escaped:

```
 array('"aaaa"', '"bbb"')
```

In the CSV you have:

```
"""aaaa""","""bbb"""
```

> ```
> Fields with embedded double-quote characters must be quoted, and each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a
> ```
>
> pair of double-quote characters.
>
> 1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values